# Using modulo on a range of numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, modulo

I'm making a program in ruby to find all of the prime factors of a given number. I'm aware that ruby has a .Prime class, but I'd like to accomplish this without using it.

Everything is working well except for one catch: I can't find a way to run modulo on a range of numbers. I've tried to find an answer online, in the Ruby documentation, and on older posts here. So far I've found nothing that helped.

Here's the code:

```
def prime(n)
    r = Range.new(2, n-1)
    r.each { |x| puts x if n % x == 0 && x % (2..x-1) != 0}
end

print "Please enter a number: "
prime(gets.chomp.to_i)
```

EDIT: Sorry, I may have been vague. This bit of code:

```
x % (2..x-1) != 0
```

Kicks back this:

```
euler2.rb:3:in `%': Enumerator can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
        from euler2.rb:3:in `block in divisible'
        from euler2.rb:3:in `each'
        from euler2.rb:3:in `divisible'
        from euler2.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I've googled that error, but with no luck. If I change the code to a non-range, it works.

Comment: By 'run modulo on a range of numbers' what do you mean?  It seems you're already doing that.  What's the expected output?

Comment: I think I get it now.

Comment: Just a hint, you only have to check up to sqrt(n), not n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. You try something much simpler like:

```
def prime(n)
  !(2..n-1).detect{|x| n%x == 0}
end
```

Here [detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) will return the first value of `x` that matches the condition `n%x == 0`. If none matches `nil` is returned. Therefore in case of a prime number `(2..n-1).detect{|x| n%x == 0}` will return `nil` and `!` will make it `true`. For composite numbers their lowest divisor will be returned and `!` will make it `false`.

**What is wrong with your code?**

you are doing `x % (2..x-1)`. Here `(2..x-1)` is a Range. You cannot do modulo of a Fixnum with a Range. Hence you will get:

```
TypeError: Range can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

You can improve `x % (2..x-1)` using something like `(2..x-1).each{|n| x%n}` or any other Enumerator in place of `each`. However I still think your logic is overly complicated or a simple problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

How about `any?`?

```
def prime(n)
  range = Range.new(2, n-1)
  composite = range.any? { |i| n%i == 0 }

  !composite
end
```

Of course this is going to be slow for large numbers.